# Bringing non-eu partner while on a Blue Card in Germany

Tags: germany, family, marriage, blue-card

I am a non-EU citizen, not married, but in a longterm relationship with another non-EU person.

Currently I am applying for a Blue Card visa to Germany.

I have two questions:

1) Is it possible to bring a non-married partner with you on a Blue Card to Germany? If yes, what are the ways to prove our relationship? I keep finding some contradicting info on that matter.

2) If we get married **after** I get the Blue Card, can we immediately apply for family reunification or there's some cooldown period?

Comment: **to** Germany or **in** Germany? Are you applying from outside of Germany? Nationality of both persons would be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the question. We both are citizens of Russia, currently living on a working visas in Czech Republic, going to apply from CZ.

Comment: and thanks, I have updated the wording in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the **Visumhandbuch** of July 2018

- which is a collection of Guidlines on how the visa's should be issued / processed

**§19a AufentG Blu Card EU** only meantions **married couples and children**

- **non married couples** are not mentioned at all

---

1) This is an area which must be clarified at the consulate or with a lawyer.

- proof must be laid forward that would satisfy the official

2) **yes**, a Blue Card holder can apply for spouse and children up to the age of 16 (with exceptions up to 18)

- the spouse does **not** have to fulfill language requirements that may otherwise be a prerequirement
- they will also be eligible for a **unrestricted** work permit
- no meantion of a time restriction
- condition **§30 g**

**Note:** persons who fulfill the condition **§30 d** (general, normal permits)

- may only apply for a spouse reunion after **2 years**

---

Source inside Visahandbuch

- **VHB Beitrag 'Blaue Karte EU'**

  - IV (5) Familiennachzug

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!
As for point #2, Im finding following parts in articles:
If you got married after your spouse was awarded a residence permit, you may be required to wait until your spouse has had the permit for two years before you can apply. Your local German embassy or consulate can inform you what applies in your situation.
(https://www.expatica.com/de/moving/visas/german-family-reunion-visa-to-join-a-relative-or-partner-in-germany-108796/)

But I haven't managed to find any official documents that confirm that point.

Comment: This looks as if it does **not apply** to your case. (see apdaped text) Found information about non marriage conditions. They seem permitted to judge in a case by case mannor. If your Czech papers imply that you are an unmarried couple, that **may** be enough.